# What is the best way to keep user information entered in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have some users information like personal information and profile image. I need to user these information thought my web application.
I've created a public class that I set to users when I log in and I use the fields in that class in the entire web application.
Is this the right way?
Is there a better way to use this information at no cost?

Note: I have more than 2000 users in the user table.

Login Action:

```
var user = new LoginAction().getLogin(obj);
if (user!=null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(obj.Username, false);
    Helper.loginUser = user;
}
```

Helper Class:

```
public static tblUser loginUser;
```

Comment: Store the data in a database, look it up as needed. `static` won't work - since that will be shared **across** logged in users.

Comment: @mjwills data is in database. i need to keep user information in temporary location.

Comment: `Cache` is likely your best bet then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static class in not good choice for storing users profile in memory. First problem is that `Helper.loginUser` always has last logged in user profile. [Session](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/simple-login-application-using-Asp-Net-mvc/) and [Cache](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/local-data-caching-in-asp-net-web-application3/) are better choice to keep users profile in memory and after user logout or expiring session memory will be freed.

```
var user = new LoginAction().getLogin(obj);
if (user!=null)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(obj.Username, false);
    Session["User"] = user;
}
```